# Joining QuerySets from different tables

Tags: sql-server, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to use Django to create reports from a legacy MS SQL application. The application includes two identical schemas for storing tickets, one called Requests, the other ArchiveRequests.

I would like to create a single QuerySet that holds data from both tables. This can be done in T-SQL like this

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
  FROM [AmCatHDSQL].[dbo].[ArchiveRequests]
UNION SELECT *
  FROM [AmCatHDSQL].[dbo].[Requests]
```

However trying to union them using the `|` operator raises an `AssertionError`, Cannot combine queries on two different base models.

Is there a way to tell Django that these models are identical and can be unioned, or is there a better way to reference these (as a single model?)

Comment: create a SP in SQL SERVER and call from PYTHON

Comment: If you need read-only access, consider a DB view with data from both tables and a corresponding Django model.